# Can't install Google Apps

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread

I'm using an Allview Alldro P2 phone with Android 2.3.5. Fresh out of the box it worked like a charm. After a factory reset from Settings I couldn't install any apps from Google (Gmail, Youtube, etc).

Later edit : Gmail failed, Youtube failed, Google Maps worked... odd right?

I'm getting an error like "Problem parsing package" but if I download other apps, they work like a charm.

Any ideas? It's the first time I'm having this issue. Meanwhile I will be exploring this site for any clues.

Thank you.

Comment: Does Google Play work on it? Google Apps work on a special framework which your phone might be lacking? I know the Kindle Fire lacks the framework but I don't know if any other devices do.

Comment: maybe, but in the processes i see google services running, does factory resetting a phone cause such problems on other models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is taking place when you install Google apps APKs directly on phone.

The solution is installing Google apps image in ***Recovery mod***.

You can always get the **latest GApps** for any android version such as Ice Cream Sandwich (Android 4.0.x), Honeycomb (Android 3.x), Gingerbread (Android 2.3.x), Froyo (Android 2.2.x) and Eclair (Android 2.1.x) from this address **[Latest GAPPSS](http://wiki.rootzwiki.com/Google_Apps)**

Comment: so it isn't an issue with the fact that i did a factory reset? also, why install from recovery mode?